# Guessing filters from responses to step signals

Tags: filters, impulse-response, reconstruction, step-response

*This is a [cross-post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/557836/guessing-filters-from-responses-to-step-signals) from CrossValidated SE where I did get no definite answer.*

---

Consider a signal $X$ filtered by a kernel $p$ with finite support $[t_0,t_1]$ and $\int_{t_0}^{t_1}p(t)\,\text{d}t = 1$, yielding the response function

$$\overline{X}(T) = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} X(T + t)\ p(t)\ \text{d}t$$

The response function for a step signal $X(t) = H(t)$ with $H$ being the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) immediately gives $p(t)$:

$$\overline{X}(T) = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} H(T + t)\ p(t)\ \text{d}t = \int_{t_0+T}^{t_1+
T} H(t)\ p(t-T)\ \text{d}t \\= \int_{0}^{t_1+
T} p(t-T)\ \text{d}t = P(t_1) - P(-T)$$

Here $P$ is the anti-derivative of $p$ with $P(t) = \int_{-\infty}^t p(t')\ \text{d}t'$ so with $P(t_1) = 1$ we find $P(T) = 1 - \overline{X}(-T)$ and finally

$$p(t) = \overline{X'}(t)$$

I wonder if this finding has a specific name (that I can google for), and if it is worth being explicitly mentioned in textbooks (e.g. on signal processing). Or on the other hand, if it is too elementary or even trivial to be mentioned. (I have searched a bit and did not find it explicitly mentioned.)

Comment: we just call $p$ the impulse response, and it's usually what we use to characterize a system. I'm, however, not quite sure what your *finding* is, could you somehow highlight that?

Comment: @MarcusMüller: I defined $p$ as the filter kernel (possibly not quite correct) and $\overline{X}$ to be the recorded signal (as opposed to the original signal $X$), calling it the reponse function of $X$. The "finding" is, that the filter kernel is immediately given by (the derivative of) the recorded signal $\overline{X}$ of an original step-like signal $X$. Please correct me, when I misused terms.

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker: That's indeed a correct (and very well-known) result. See my answer below.

Comment: calling $p$ a filter kernel is totally OK, the image processing people tend to call it that way, as well.

Comment: Well, if you write out $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dT} \bar X(T) =\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dT} \int_{t_0}^{t_1} H(T + t)\ p(t)\ \text{d}t$, you'll notice that you can commute the integral and the derivative operator, so that you're just convolving $p$ with the "derivative" of the step function, which strictly speaking doesn't exist, but if you're allowed to use tempered distributions, can be represented by the Dirac $\delta$, exactly the distribution you need to multiply your integrand with to let the result of the integral be the integrand.

Comment: By the way, you can either argue through linearity of integral and derivative, or through Fubini's theorem to arrive at the commutability of the integral and derivative operation

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Thanks a lot for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well-known result with no specific name. In signal processing, we usually call the kernel *impulse response* (as correctly mentioned in a comment by Marcus Müller). The response to a unit step signal is called *step response*. So what you've found is how to compute the impulse response from the step response.

If $h(t)$ denotes the impulse response of a (linear and time-invariant) system, and $a(t)$ denotes its step response, we have

$$a(t)=\int_{-\infty}^th(\tau)d\tau\tag{1}$$

and

$$h(t)=a'(t)\tag{2}$$

where $a'(t)$ denotes the derivative of $a(t)$.

Note that for $(1)$ and $(2)$ to hold, we do not require the impulse response to have finite support.

The result $(2)$ is obvious if we note that we could differentiate the unit step at the input to obtain an impulse and, consequently, obtain the impulse response at the system's output. Since differentiation is also just a linear time-invariant operation, we can exchange it with our (linear time-invariant) system, and, instead of differentiating at the input, take the derivative of the output to obtain the same result, namely the system's impulse response.

Comment: Thanks. What's confusing for the novice is that a filter is called a response. Mathematically it is clear because $\overline{X}(T) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(T+t)p(t)\text{d}t = p(-T)$. But from the conceptual point of view, the filter is something else than any response that derives from it, isn't it?

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker: We don't call a filter a "response". A filter is *characterized* by its impulse response, because knowing its response to an impulse, we can compute its response to any input signal. (All of this obviously only holds for linear systems).

Comment: as Matt says, the filter is not called the response. $p$ is *the filter's impulse response*; the *filter* itself is the system that maps a signal to another signal. To make this clear, your $p: \mathbb R \mapsto \mathbb C$, and the actual filter, let's call it $\xi$, maps $X$ to $\bar X$, i.e. $\xi:\mathbb (\mathbb R \mapsto \mathbb C) \mapsto (\mathbb R \mapsto \mathbb C)$.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: But you call the **kernel** the response, right? "We usually call the kernel impulse response." So it's about the difference between filter and kernel?

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker: The kernel IS the system's response to an impulse, i.e., its "impulse response".

Comment: exactly. kernel $\equiv$ impulse reponse $\ne$ filter.

Comment: In DSP notation: $$y(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-\tau)h(\tau)d\tau=h(t)$$

Comment: Now I got it, thanks for your help!

Comment: Adding a note just in case:  the impulse response is very popular as a system description since it forms a Fourier Transform pair with the transfer function.